# How can I move an existing User Story to another Area (Path)?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We are using TFS2013. Some of our User Stories are created as children of Epics and inherit those epics' Area Path (e.g. "Release 3.0").
Some User Stories were created independently and then linked to the Epic in question. Those got a different Area Path (e.g. "Release 2.0"). Now we want to modify the Area Path of the User Stories to match that of the Epic they are attached to.
The UI in VS2012 and the web UI don't allow me to modify the Area Path (field is displayed but disabled). Neither does an export to Excel. Even using a TFS admin account I found no way to do that.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is Epic a custom work item? Do you apply rules to User Story work item or customize the User Story work item? I've tried linking a default User Story work item to a default Feature work item in TFS 2013, the Area Path field in User Story work item can be modified without any issue.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Epic is a custom work item. Good question about rules. I will check.

Comment: Have you checked the rules? Any helpful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linking a default User Story work item to a default Feature work item in TFS 2013, the Area Path field in User Story work item can be modified without any issue, I assume there are rules applied to the User Story work item, you may check it.

Also, check the [permission on an area path](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/modify-areas-iterations#set-permissions-to-restrict-access-to-work-items) to see whether you have appropriate permission to edit work item under an area path.

Comment: Sorry, that took forever but your tip was spot on. Thx!